# Can't use quick watch wile debugin in if statement Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, if-statement

The problem looks like this:

I have an if statements in my code.

```
if (tcd.TrescWartosc != null)
                    {
                        var document = new ISDocument();
                        document.DocContent = tcd.TrescWartosc;
                        int count = 0;
                        int count2 = 0;
                        count = count + 2;
                    }
```

It's just a fragment of the code inside the statement and some variables that I've added to test my errors (count and count2)
The problem is that when i debug the project in this one "if" when i check any variable I'm getting 'don't exist in the current context' error. When I comment out the if fragment everything is ok. I've tried with if(true) and the problem remains so what could be the reason for this?? Pin to source also shows nothing...

Comment: Which variables are you checking? count and count2, or other global ones?

Comment: Different ones and still the same..Inside this "if" existed a black debug hole :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was visual studio itself...Above I had another if with code and statement like

```
 if (!tcd.Wyslano)
                    {
                    ...
                    ...
                    }
```

I wanted to ommit that "if" so I've replaced  `if (!tcd.Wyslano)` with `if(false)` and Visual Studio had some problem with that...I've replaced it now with `if (!tcd.Wyslano && false)` and now it debugs ok so i thinks it was kind of VS bug...